# Does native functionality exist in spark sql for excluding fields after issuing a "select *"? (e.g. - "select * <except> field1, field2, fieldn")

Tags: apache-spark-sql

My primary use case for this is when working with spark. I use spark.sql to query the contents of multiple tables into data frames and then I join on common fields. The problem is that some of these tables contain fields that share the same name (e.g. - createdate) and this results in an error. I have been working around this by specifying all of the fields except the ones that are duplicates. This is time consuming.

Comment: If you run a query with SparkSQL, then you don't run a query with Hive. They have (slightly) different SQL syntax and (heavily) different query execution engines. Please edit the title -- and the tags -- to remove the confusion.

Comment: You know that Spark lets you retrieve the list of columns for each table (cf. metadata catalog) or each DataFrame, right? So why don't you develop a function for generating **automatically** the list of output columns in proper SQL syntax to handle join keys (keep only one set) and attributes (keep original names except when there is a conflict that needs an extra suffix) -- e.g. `a.KEY_1, a.KEY_2,  a.ATTR_3, a.ATTR_4, b.ATTR_4 as ATTR_4_B, b.ATTR_5` to help you build the SQL query?

Comment: I did not know that. Thank you for the suggestion, I will try it.